# Increase gap (pause) between songs

Tags: macos, itunes

I need a real GAP between songs. I mean a REAL pause, about two seconds. Why? My MD player can't handle songs if there are no gaps in line input. Even with a one second gap MD records two songs as one.

I know that there's an option in preference to switch off cross fading, but this is not what I want to do. Cross fading doesn't add any gap at all. If there's no gap between two songs you won't hear any pause and I want that pause.

Is there any software for Mac OS X or an iTunes plugin that can increase the gap in the playlist? I know that WinAmp has a plugin for putting pauses between songs.

Another work around is to add a two second MP3 between each song in the playlist but this is really killing me and painful to do.

I'm more on lossless stuff, so .CUE files would be an option too (using XLD for converting).

Comment: Are you sure that you can't modify the recording settings of your MD player?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a cross-fading option for your player. Increase or decrease to make the songs overlap or have a silence between them. Search for a cross-fade plugin if iTunes does not support it natively.